# how to upload files using submithandler function(form) jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to post images files using :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#upload").validate({
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.post("upload.php", {
                        file: $("#file").val()                  
                        }
```

I have tried this, its posting in the upload.php but file is not uploading, Can anyone help me in this code?

Comment: Please see [ask] and create a [mcve] using snippet `<>` tool.

Comment: I'm sorry, i am new here, If you can't help please just ignore.

Comment: Trying to help. Questions that do not meet expectations are often closed.

Comment: okay thanks for the help.

Comment: What the OP has already seems like a minimal complete example already.  It doesn't work, but the OP has explained the symptoms.  It's not a lot of code, and while the html isn't included, it's fairly obvious.